# Spring mongodb get ID of inserted item after Save

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I am working with Spring MongoDb.

I create various entities using `insert` method:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#insert-java.lang.Object-

However, all methods return `void`. I need to return the `ObjectId` of the inserted document.

What is the best way to get it?

Comment: `If your object has an "Id' property, it will be set with the generated Id from MongoDB`, have an attribute called `Id`. Once this method is called, the Object you passed will have its `Id` attribute filled.

Comment: Moreover you need not return anything, since the object would be mutable.

Comment: Thanks. I would need to return it in the response of my REST API. I have an API exposed to create a document

Comment: Okay, you can always do `insert(someObject);` `return someObject.getId()`.

Comment: To return id you need to expose them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480782/id-missing-in-the-json-response-with-spring-data-in-mongodb

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is pretty interesting and thought I would share. I just figured out the solution for this with the help of BatScream comment above:

You would create an object and insert it into your MongoDB:

```
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    animal.setName(name);
    animal.setCat(cat);

    mongoTemplate.insert(animal);
```

Your animal class looks like this with getters and settings for all fields:

```
public class Animal {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String cat;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

AFTER you have done the insert under `mongoTemplate.insert(animal);`, you can actually call the method `animal.getId()` and it will return back the ObjectId that was created.

Comment: I tried `mongoOperations.insert(thing)`, followed by `thing.getId()`, but it returned `null`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with @AlanH that `animal.getId()` is `null`. And then I just realized my id field had been set as a final field with a `wither` method. So of course `getId()` is null since the id field is immutable and the `wither` method returns a new object with id.

if this is the case: use `animal = template.insert(animal)`.