# id missing in the json response with spring data in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am saving a object using spring data in a mongo db. But i can not see the created id return with the json response object.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
@ApiModel(description = "Submission")
public class Submission {

    @Id
    private String submissionId;
    private String assignmentId;
    private String title;

}

public interface SubmissionRepository extends MongoRepository<Submission, String>{

}
```

Below is what i do inside the controller,

```
Submission sub= submissionService.createSubmission(submission);
return new ResponseEntity<>(sub, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

Even the sub object has the submissionId populate, but it does not comes with the response json object as a property. Any clue what only submissionId is missing from reponse?

Even with get request the id is not coming with the response. I am using spring boot environment with spring-data-mongodb-1.6.3

Comment: The ID in REST – as the name suggests – is the URI, hence the self link.

Comment: i didnt get your point

Comment: The client must not care about an artificially introduced property to satisfy a particular backend. Resources on the REST level are identified by their URIs, so this artificial backend identifier is omitted by default. Just like a version property is as it's translated into an ETag header, i.e. the protocol specific means to represent that property of the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this by creating a config class as below,

```
@Configuration
public class RestDataConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration{
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config)
    {
        super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Assignment.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

So *Harshana* has it right for Spring Boot 1.3.0 . You can just toss each class you want the id exposed for right under `config.exposeIdsFor(Assignment.class)`.  It worked for me now as well. So my answer below is just an alternative.

Also if you want HAL JSON to JSON API (aka Spring Boot Backend and Ember Data Frontend) [Ember-Data-Hal-9000](https://github.com/201-created/ember-data-hal-9000) has worked well for Ember Data 1.13.x .

---

The accepted answer did not work for me in Spring Boot. Instead I created an alias of `id`  and used the Jackson annotation `@JsonProperty("id")`

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

 public class Calculation {

    @Id private String id;

    private String equation;
    private String result;

    @JsonProperty ("id")
    private String emberId;


    public String getEmberId() {
        return id;
    }
```

(since Ember Data needed one and using regex to pull it out of

```
_links: {
  self: {
    href: "http://localhost:4201/calculations/562796702b5e0940c66593fe"
   }
}
```

didn't sound like much fun in an Ember Adapter). Hope this helps somebody later.

Update looks like someone did put together a [hal serializer](https://github.com/locks/ember-data-hal-adapter/blob/master/lib/hal-serializer.js), if you want to handle this in the client with Ember.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a public `getId()` in your `Assignment.class`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I create a configuration class like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config)
    {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Brand.class);
    }
}
```

and it works