# how can get the last inserted value in spring mongodb?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

i have a class Named Device

```
@Document
public class Devise 
{

@Id
public String id;
public String reference;
@DBRef
public List<Mesures> listMes;

public Devise() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Devise(String reference, List<Mesures> listMes) {
    super();
    this.reference = reference;
    this.listMes = listMes;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

public List<Mesures> getListMes() {
    return listMes;
}

public void setListMes(List<Mesures> listMes) {
    this.listMes = listMes;
}

}
```

another class named Mesures

```
@Document
public class Mesures {

@Id
private String id;
private Double value;
private Date date;
@DBRef
private Devise devise;

public Mesures() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Mesures(Double value, Date date, Devise devise) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.date = date;
    this.devise = devise;
}

public Mesures(Double value, Date date) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.date = date;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Double getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Double value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Devise getDevise() {
    return devise;
}

public void setDevise(Devise devise) {
    this.devise = devise;
}
```

and this is the MesuresRepository who extend from Mongo Repository

```
public interface MesureRepository extends MongoRepository<Mesures, String>{
public Mesures findTopByDeviseOrderByDateDesc(String DeviseId);

}
```

and this is the main app (Spring boot app)

```
  ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    MesureDAO MDAO = ctx.getBean(MesureDAO.class);
    DeviceDAO DDAO = ctx.getBean(DeviceDAO.class);


    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss");
    Mesures m1 = new Mesures(10.0, df.parse("2016-11-12-12-51-42"));
    Mesures m2 = new Mesures(15.2,df.parse("2016-11-12-12-52-42"));
    //add Mesure
    MDAO.addMesure(m1);
    MDAO.addMesure(m2);
    List<Mesures>listMes = new ArrayList<>();
    listMes.add(m1);
    listMes.add(m2);
    //add Device
    Devise D = new Devise("G2fgG123", listMes);
    DDAO.addDevice(D);
```

and the database look like :

```
 db.devise.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bc8218d980530898a0b047"),
    "_class" : "demo.model.Devise",
    "reference" : "G2fgG123",
    "listMes" : [
            DBRef("mesures", ObjectId("58bc8218d980530898a0b045")),
            DBRef("mesures", ObjectId("58bc8218d980530898a0b046"))
    ]
}
```

and the restController like this

```
@RestController
public class MesuressController {
@Autowired
MesureRepository mesureRepo;
@RequestMapping(value = "/mesure/{DeviseId}")
public Mesures findByDeviseIdOrderByDate(@PathVariable("DeviseId")String  DeviseId) {
    return mesureRepo.findTopByDeviseIdOrderByDateDesc(DeviseId);
}}
```

and this is the measure Doc

```
db.mesures.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bc8218d980530898a0b045"),
    "_class" : "demo.model.Mesures",
    "value" : 10,
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-11T23:51:42Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bc8218d980530898a0b046"),
    "_class" : "demo.model.Mesures",
    "value" : 15.2,
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-11T23:52:42Z")
}
```

and this the device document after changing

```
 db.devise.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bd306500ff6d1670916a7d"),
    "_class" : "demo.model.Devise",
    "reference" : "G2fgG123",
    "listMes" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("58bd306500ff6d1670916a7b"),
                    "value" : 10,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-11T23:51:42Z")
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("58bd306500ff6d1670916a7c"),
                    "value" : 15.2,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-11T23:52:42Z")
            }
    ]
```

Comment: may be duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986183/spring-mongodb-get-id-of-inserted-item-after-save

Comment: How is `device` in `Mesures` associated ? You may want to create a `DBRef`.

Comment: the same thing it returns a white page without any error

Comment: So let me understand this correctly you are trying to get the `Mesures` record by `deviseId` correct ? If yes you have to save the reference of `device` in `Mesures` doc. Please correct me if I am wrong or better update the question  with input and expected output.

Comment: i'm trinng to get the last record by deviseId . and why i should save the reference of device in mesures ? in the next time i will receive this measures from cloud because i'm working with gauge and evrey period of time it must update itself with the last value . so evrey time the sript request this URL :"dataStreamUrl": "http://localhost:8080/mesures/id" it shoud give me the lastest value

Comment: The only reason I said that is because you are using `MesureRepository` which is repository over `Mesures` collection and it doesn't have `devise` reference for you to query on `deviseId`.  How will you know to pull `Mesures` for a given `deviseId` ? So other option is  have to change to use `DeviseRepository` which can only be queried by `mesureId` for `mesures`(meaning you cant use `date`)

Comment: evrey period of time the Device will sent the id of the device(reference) and the value x(variable during the time) wihcich is Mesure

Comment: I think the the solution would be to not use `DBRef` when you have to access the `Mesure` collection by `value`. You can add the `Mesure`s as embedded documents in the `Devise` collection and access them.

Comment: in other word would say to get List of Mesures by deviceId ? but how i can get the last value in this case ?

Comment: yes that is an option too with current structure and than you do the sorting on the java side and pick the latest one by date.

Comment: what do you mean by as embedded documents in the Devise

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#array-match-embedded-documents. Look at field `instock`

Comment: do you mean to retreive @Dbref from Mesures ? after this change the same thing :/

Comment: I thought little bit more about this. Can you just keep one collection where you store `mesure` information by `deviseId`? Something like `"_id" : ObjectId("58bd306500ff6d1670916a7d"),
    "_class" : "demo.model.Mesures",
    "reference" : "G2fgG123", "value" : 10,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-11T23:51:42Z")}` and after that you can use `public Mesures findTopByReferenceOrderByDateDesc(String reference);`. You can remove all the `DBRef`. Let me know what do you think.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mongodb's $natural operator:

```
Query query = new Query().with(new Sort(Direction.ASC, "$natural"));

BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(new BasicDBObject());
basicQuery.setSortObject(new BasicDBObject("$natural", -1));
```